# Source of Chasal Sidur Pesach?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

I have read that this piyut was intended to be recited on Shabbat Hagadol. Where does it first appear? Who wrote it?

Comment: To give you some context, if you've ever heard a shiur about how repentance on the high holidays works that cites the poem Unetane Tokef, imagine there was a famous poem that everyone read at pesach time that served as everyone's basic legal primer for that holiday. That was this poem for all Ashkenazi Jews until ~100 years ago when people lost interest in prayer poetry (for reasons beyond the scope of this comment)

Answer (score 3):

These lines are the conclusion of one of the *piyyutim* for Shabbat HaGadol, composed by [R. Joseph b. Samuel Bonfils (*Tuv 'Elem*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Samuel_Bonfils) (11th century CE) and recited in Minhag Ashkenaz during *chazarat hashatz* of *shacharit*.

To quote from the above-linked Wikipedia page:

> Of his many piyyuṭim, the best-known is that written for "Shabbat HaGadol" (the Sabbath before Passover), beginning with the words "Elohei haruchot," and containing the rules for the Passover-cleaning ("bi'ur") and the narrative service for the evening. **Its concluding lines, beginning with "Hasal seder pesach", appear near the end of the Passover Haggadah.**

Comment: Also worth noting another poem from this collection which made it into the post-seder: אז רוב ניסים. If you've ever caught someone singing וכל מאמינים or היום תאמצינו in the days following Rosh Hashanah, you now understand how these popular poems began to be sung after the Seder.

Comment: Why would it change from (IMO the more accurate) Chasal SEDER Pesach to Chasal Siddur Pesach?

Answer (score 1):

It is ascribed to רב יוסף טוב עלם as can be seen in the articles below with the Hebrew Wikipedia articles containing more extensive information.

[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/אבוא_בחיל_להתיצבה](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%94) (Chasal Sidur Pesach appears as the finale of this larger piyut)

[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יוסף_טוב_עלם](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%9D)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Samuel_Bonfils

Perhaps further examination of the sources in these articles will mention where the piyut first appeared.